# .equals not working with scanner

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I know it's reading the file because I have it print the contents of the txt file to the console but everytime I try .equals the variable doesn't change to true/false just stays at true any ideas?

```
public static void readWebPage() {
      URLConnection connection;
      try {
       connection = new URL("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/40562795/List.txt").openConnection();
       @SuppressWarnings("resource")
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
       scanner.useDelimiter("\\z");
       String text = scanner.next();
        System.out.println(text);
        if(text.equals("stop")){
            stop = true;
            System.out.println("Successfully stopped.");
        }else{ if(text.equals("-"))
            stop = false;
            System.out.println("Successfully started.");
        }
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
 }
```

*Edit:*

That worked it's able to read it now, but my variable isn't updating to true/false. It stays at true or so this says in the console.

```
if(stop = false){
    System.out.println("stop = false.");
}else
if(stop = true){
    System.out.println("stop = true.");
}
```

How my variable is made:

```
 public static boolean stop = false;
```

That's how I've made the variable and it should = false but stop nor - change it. I searched my java files for something that may be triggering it to true and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Maybe there are spaces or \n in your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a trailing space after the `-` character in the remote text file. You could use a whitespace delimiter rather than a line terminator delimiter. Replace

```
scanner.useDelimiter("\\z");
```

with

```
scanner.useDelimiter("\\s+");
```

so that your `text` will match your `.equals` checks.

**Edit:**

From the edit, you have an assignment in your `if` statement expression:

```
if (stop = false) {
```

replace with

```
if (stop == false) {
```

or better

```
if (!stop) {
```

Overall this `if` statement is unnecessary, you can simply write

```
System.out.println("stop = " + stop);
```